# What is the top-level of a list?

Tags: scheme

Suppose I defined a list in scheme : (list (list 1 2) (list 3 4) (list 5 6))
Is the top-level the first sublist?

Comment: I'd say the `top-level` list is the list that holds the sublists, not any sublist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top-level list in the example is the list that contains as its three elements `(1 2) (3 4) (5 6)`. The top-level is *not* `(1 2)` - the first sublist: it's the list that *contains* that sublist. Given that all the list elements in the example are sublists, the top level list in `((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))` is seen as the left-most and right-most parenthesis.

Comment: uhm if i have (list (list 1 2) (list 3 4) (list 5 6) 9 8)

then 9 8 will be elements in the top-level list too right including the sublists?

Comment: @ms.sakura that's right, 9 and 8 are elements at the same level that the other three sublists, and all of them (5 elements in total) belong to the top level list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The top-level are the elements in the list. Some of those elements happen to be lists themselves. In this case, there is only one element, which happens to be a list.